# Replace .php with backslash

Tags: nginx

How would my `try_files` look if I wanted to have `http://mydomain/script/` instead of `http://mydomain/script.php` ?

Sorry I couldn't find an answer anywhere, perhaps I worded the question wrong

Comment: Google along the lines of "clean/pretty URLs nginx php"

Comment: Also, that's a forward slash, not a backslash.

Comment: I am trying to configure auto-exchanger, it seems that if the url is `http://mydomain/script/` script.php would be called but if the domain is `http://mydomain/script/some/extra` the latter two are passed as GET requests. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Move your into a folder named **`script`** and rename it to be **`index.php`**

Comment: Not an option in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Is the slash at the end an absolute requirement?  If not, the url `http://mydomain/script` would work if your try_files looked like this:

```
try_files "${uri}.php" $uri =404;
```